# i can't listing users' post in theirs profile. i use one to many relationship in User model

Tags: php, laravel

***//here is my controller*** `

public function index($id){

```
    $users=User::where('id',$id)->get();

    return view('user',compact('users'));

}
```

}`

***//here is my User model***

```
   public function getPosts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post','user_id','id');
}
```

***//here is my user blade***

```
 @foreach($user->getPosts as $post)
        <div class="profile-content">
            <section class="post-heading">
                <div class="rows">
                    <div class="col-md-11">

                        <div class="media">
                            <div class="media-left">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="media-object photo-profile" src="https://scontent.fgyd4-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/p960x960/73248174_2597397730318615_6397819353256951808_o.jpg?_nc_cat=109&_nc_sid=7aed08&_nc_ohc=VxH_cAqJ778AX_7B97W&_nc_ht=scontent.fgyd4-2.fna&_nc_tp=6&oh=e5b02c7f91818664cf253e71f2ddf106&oe=5F5F4E74" width="40" height="40" alt="...">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <a href="/users" class="anchor-username"><h4 class="media-heading">{{$user->name}} </h4></a>
                                <a href="#" class="anchor-time">{{$user->$post['created_at']}}</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </section>


            <section class="post-body">

                <p>{{  $user->getPost->post['post_description']  }}</p> <!--  i stick around here -->
            </section>
```

***//it give this error to me***

**Property [getPosts] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\site\resources\views\user.blade.php)**

Comment: You're passing `users` to the view but are using `user` in the view. Those are different variables so I'm more surprised that you don't get _"undefined variable"_

Answer (score 1):

In controller get() will return collection,you want one user, so use find() or first(), it will return one user object

```
public function index($id){

    $user=User::find($id); //or $user=User::where('id',$id)->first();

    return view('user',compact('user'));

}
```

Relation method

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post','user_id','id');
}
```

Since their is one to many relation between user and posts,you have to use loop to show posts for a user

```
foreach($user->posts as $post)
        <div class="profile-content">
            <section class="post-heading">
                <div class="rows">
                    <div class="col-md-11">

                        <div class="media">
                            <div class="media-left">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="media-object photo-profile" src="https://scontent.fgyd4-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/p960x960/73248174_2597397730318615_6397819353256951808_o.jpg?_nc_cat=109&_nc_sid=7aed08&_nc_ohc=VxH_cAqJ778AX_7B97W&_nc_ht=scontent.fgyd4-2.fna&_nc_tp=6&oh=e5b02c7f91818664cf253e71f2ddf106&oe=5F5F4E74" width="40" height="40" alt="...">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <a href="/users" class="anchor-username"><h4 class="media-heading">{{$user->name}} </h4></a>
                                <a href="#" class="anchor-time">{{$post->created_at}}</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </section>


            <section class="post-body">

                <p>{{  $post->post_description  }}</p> <!--  i stick around here -->
            </section>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

`$users=User::where('id',$id)->get()`; returns a collection of users

So when you do this:

`@foreach($user->getPosts as $post)`

`$user` is a collection of users. That collection doesn't have a getPosts() method.

Comment: `$users`  och `$user` are two completely different variables though.

Comment: you might add that one should call `User::findOrFail($id)` or something like `->first()` to get a single instance

Comment: Yes, you are right but anyways `foreach($users->getPosts as $post)` won't work, right?

Comment: @PawełPłonka yes exactly, that won't work because it is a collection :)

Comment: but i use "where id=$id" and should it return one of users for where clause?  and I users collection for another places in same blade. if I change it, another codes will collapse

Comment: No, look here:
https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_get
`get()` method returns collection  

If you want to receive one element (User) you shoud use `first()` (as @Aless55 wrote)

Comment: @azerbaijan_wr if you need both, just pass both to your blade?

Comment: Yes, so you can do: `$user = User::where('id',$id)->first();` and `$users = User::all();`
and then push it to template: `return view('user',compact('user', 'users'));`

Answer (score 0):

you are returning list of users, so you don't have one user and you can't have the posts of all certain user

below code can fix the issue:

```php
   User::where('id', $id)->first();
```

Comment: but i use "where id=$id" and should it return one of users for where clause?

Comment: no, It will return the model and depends on your preference, you can get all of the collection with ```get()``` or one instance with ```first()```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should update your controller like this

```
User::find($id);
```

You should update your relation like this

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post','user_id','id');
}
```

After that you should update your blade like this

```
foreach ($user->posts as $post)
```

You can't access posts with `->getPosts`. If you want, you should use like this `->getPosts()->get()`